# Android emulation

Tags: android, android-emulator

How to make the emulator run with a different sim serial number / phone number, etc...

Any help will be appreciated...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it looks possible; see [this](http://codepainters.wordpress.com/2010/09/06/android-emulator-and-the-sim-card-serial-number/).